# Error to load Glide Image Android

Tags: android, image, ssl, android-glide

Hi I have a very strange problem.

I have my backend in Back4app and I have a class with a column: image.
The url of the image is like "https://..." I try to load it with Glide using

`Glide.with(context)
    .load("https://back4app...image.png")
    .into(imageView);`

No image load.
I said it is strange because before it run, but now I get the ssl error.

What is the problem? I note that when I change the url from "https" to "http" it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  Glide.with(this).load("url").into(imageView);
```

[Glide Example](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

**Make sure that you added internet permission and also check the url.**

Comment: I have the next permission

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: then check the image url

Answer (score 0):

This is due to SSL exception. You may check this article : https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-accepting-self-signed-https-certificates